# Improving Matlab code speed for summing two big arrays

Tags: performance, matlab

I have two Matlab arrays, `A` `B`, each of size `3085^2 x 4`. I need to implement the following procedure:

1. For each `h`-th row of `A`, `A(h,:)`, compute `A(h,1)+B(:,1)+A(h,2)+B(:,2)-(A(h,3)+B(:,3))-(A(h,4)+B(:,4))` and store `min` and `max` of the obtained `3085^2x1` vector.
2. Find the overall `min` and `max` across the `min` and `max` found in the previous step.

This is how I have implemented the procedure.

```
   clear
    rng default
    sm=3085^2;
    A=randn(sm,4);
    B=randn(sm,4);
    
    
    D_interval_temp=zeros(sm,2);
    for h=1:sm
        tic
        D_temp=A(h,1)+B(:,1)+A(h,2)+B(:,2)-(A(h,3)+B(:,3))-(A(h,4)+B(:,4)); 
        D_interval_temp(h,:)=[min(D_temp) max(D_temp)];
        toc
    end
    
    D_interval=[min(D_interval_temp(:,1)); max(D_interval_temp(:,2))];
```

The issue is that my algorithm is very slow: each iteration of the loop takes 0.12 sec. Hence, the code would take approx 317 hours to complete.

**Question**: is there anything I can do to substantially improve the procedure so that it can be completed in a shorter amount of time?

I have tried to vectorise
as

```
ndgrid(1:sm, 1:sm);
cx1=cx1(:);
cx2=cx2(:);
AB=[A(cx1,:) B(cx2,:)];
```

but it goes out of memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the desired result using this:

```
BB = B(:, 1) + B(:,2) - B(:,3) - B(:,4);
AA = A(:, 1) + A(:,2) - A(:,3) - A(:,4); 
D_interval = [min(BB) max(BB)] + [min(AA) max(AA)];
```

Comment: You're right, I was focusing on OP's loop, forgot about the final min/max computation. Nice one!